# How to calculate the surface normal of a plane where each vertex is shifted up and down based on a cos(x) wave

Tags: c++, graphics, linear-algebra, trigonometry, calculus

So Here is the current code which does it correctly:

```cpp
public:
        void SetTime( float time )
        {
            t = time;
        }
        typename BaseVertexShader::Output operator()( const Vertex& v ) const
        {
            // calculate some triggy bois
            const auto angle = wrap_angle( v.pos.x * freq + t * wavelength );
            const auto cosx = std::cos( angle );
            const auto sinx = std::sin( angle );
            // sine wave amplitude from position w/ time variant phase animation
            const auto dz = amplitude * cosx;
            const auto pos = Vec4{ v.pos.x,v.pos.y,v.pos.z + dz,1.0f };
            // normal derived base on cross product of partial dx x dy
            auto n = Vec4{
                -freq * amplitude * sinx,
                0.0f,
                -1.0f,
                0.0f
            };
            n.Normalize();

            return { pos * worldViewProj,n * worldView,pos * worldView,v.t };
        }
    private:
        static constexpr float wavelength = PI;
        static constexpr float freq = 45.0f;
        static constexpr float amplitude = 0.02f;
        float t = 0.0f;
    };
```

Essentially, this is being applied to a plane. We take each vertex position x and calculate the angle based on the formulae and pass this angle to the cos function to evaluate, also sin which is used later for the derivative part.

we calculate the dz value which is how much to shift the z component up and down to create the oscilatting ripple effect on a plane. How would I calculate the dx and dy parts.

At the bottom of the code they create n and makes it x component which defines the direction of the vector, as being -freq * amplititude * sin(x) which confuses me as I do not exactly how this is derived from crossing dx and dy, whatever those values are.

Note: the axis is right handed coordinates, and the plane has rotated 90 degrees around the x direction , so the local coordinates of my plane has z pointing down and x pointing right. but my world space is z pointing into the screen , y up , and x right.

Comment: If I understand correctly, in every frame you perturbate the surface and after each perturbation you want to calculate the normal vector at each node (i,j) which has a height h(i,j). If your surface is a single valued function, you can use the Monge gauge to describe the surface. Namely r = X x + Y y + h(x,y) z. The small letters are the unit vectors and r a vector starting from (0,0) and ending at a point on the surface. In this gauge, there is an expression which 
I don't remember now but you can probably find it. If I have some time in the weekend I might write a code for it.

Comment: I think the comment is a copy-paste mishap. `cross(dx, dy)` is the typical way to calculate a normal from arbitrary geometry. In this specific case, since `d/dx(n*cos(x)) = n*sin(x)`, that process was short-circuited. I suspect whoever wrote that just forgot to amend the comment from wherever the code was originally taken from.

Comment: @Frank , wait I though the equation was just cos(x), is it because its a 2D plane right. what would he d/dy be also im confused  af

Comment: @SimonBalfe `dz = amplitude * cosx;`

Comment: @Frank so dx = n * sin(x) where n is frequency?

Comment: @SimonBalfe not frequency, amplitude, but yes. A normal is always perpendicular to the derivative, so if you know the derivative, you know the normal.

Comment: but if its amplitude also then wouldn't it be amplitude squared the cross or is it -amplitude x sin(x). what's confusing it its cross product or scalar values I swear

Comment: @Frank what is the complete derivation of how he got -freq x amp x sin im so confused

Comment: Also what would dy be im not sure how you are usin the amplitude part

Comment: @AngelosFr this is not a single valued function?

Comment: @Simon Balfe yes of course, sin and cos are single valued functions. And Frank is right about the cross product. I am wondering why it didn't come in mind. And this holds  in other gauges as well, not just the Monge. Sorry if I caused more confusion.

Comment: @AngelosFr , my surface is 2D though its described with x and y in 3D so its f(x,y) where on each timestep x is determined by the cos(x) transformation that I described.